# Is it ok to have a filter box inside a Redux container?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I know that React/Redux containers should limit JSX as much as possible and just pass props to dumb components.
Anyway, when you have a page with a filter and a list of items I tend to put the filter box inside the container and the list in a component.

This way I can use a selector in the mapStateToProps for a client-side filter and dispatch an action for a server-side filter.

Is it clean code even if I have some JSX and not just returning a dumb component in render?
Would it be better to put the filter box in a separate dumb component?

Thank you,
Matteo

Comment: Yes, it is. This whole dumb/smart components is beautiful in theory, but rather constraining in practice. Dumb/smart is an ideal that only needs to be reached gradually and when the need appears.